# Weird Floral pattern on mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh

I get these weird floral patterns on cylinders, I try to Inset the flat part of face on the top of the cylinder to create some sort of geometry to work with.

Any Ideas on how I can fix this???

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens because there is no good way to subdivide a circular face. On a cylinder, you can inset the face once or twice, so that the part with this pattern is flat, or if you have a sphere, just make a sphere with higher resolution.